# Read/Write bits for Huffman coding in java

Tags: java, netbeans, huffman-code

I have Huffman coding project that in first step we obtain code of each character depends on Huffman tree.I obtain code of each character for example : a = 01 , b= 101 , c = 111.these codes are String and i want to save them in a file with .cmp extension in binary for example we have a text such : abc and encoding is:01101111 how can i write them to a file with binary value in a file with .cmp extension and after that read them and decode them?

Comment: This question might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790654/huffman-coding-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you know that bytes and integers consist of bits, so you just need to build a little queue of bits that is a single integer containing the bits and another integer that tracks the number of bits in the first integer, accumulating bits using the shift and or operators. Once you have accumulated a byte, write it out and shift it out of your queue. E.g. to put *n* bits in `buf |= val << bits; bits += n;`, and then to pull bits out if you have enough: `while (bits >= 8) { write_out(buf & 0xff); buf >>= 8; bits -= 8;`. Make sure that you integer is large enough to handle the largest value of *n* you will have. I.e., `buf` needs to be able to hold *maxn+7* bits, since the `while` loop will never leave more than 7 bits in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work with bit streams then it is easier to take completed framework, for instance [JBBP (java binary block parser)](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) which has JBBPBitOutputStream class providing bit write operations (also there is JBBPBitInputStream class to read bits from streams)